# Calculate coordinates of point in $3$D grid by three other points with a given distance to it

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

I have a $3$D grid space and three points, $A(x, y, z)$, $B(x, y, z)$, and $C(x, y, z)$.

They all have a given distance to the fourth point $D$, which are $a$, $b$, and $c$, respectively.

How can I calculate the coordinates of the fourth point $D$ only with these three points and their distance to $D$?

I already managed to do this in $2$D with circle intersection but I can't seem to figure out how I would calculate this in $3$D space.

Comment: Here's a hint (that probably won't qualify as an answer): Maybe you can try intersecting spheres? By the way, you are encouraged to use LaTeX in your posts, although in this case it is fine.

Comment: Alright thank you. I think sphere intersection brought me onto the right path. I am sorry, I am not familiar with LaTeX

Comment: You are welcome! This is a nice first question with excellent math concepts involved (generalizing a problem, in this case from 2D to 3D). LaTeX is very easy to use and you can refer to [this tutorial](https://latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off of NNN's comment:
A sphere can be represented by the following equation
$$(x-x_o)^2 + (y-y_o)^2 + (z-z_o)^2 = r^2$$
Where $(x_o, y_o, z_o)$ is the center of the sphere and $r$ is its radius.

If you know that point $D$ is $r_A$ distance away from $A$, then you know it exists on a sphere with its center at $A(x_A,y_A,z_A)$ and a radius of $r_A$. With three data points we have three spheres:

$$(x-x_A)^2 + (y-y_A)^2 + (z-z_A)^2 = r_A^2$$
$$(x-x_B)^2 + (y-y_B)^2 + (z-z_B)^2 = r_B^2$$
$$(x-x_C)^2 + (y-y_C)^2 + (z-z_C)^2 = r_C^2$$

Now you have a system of three equations with three unknowns, $x, y, z$, which will give you the coordinates of $D$.

Comment: Though I have to say (not to criticize this answer) that the equation is a little bit (but only a little bit) cumbersome to solve so try not to solve it and find an alternate path. (Just a hint if you are not wondering this but trying to apply this into a problem).

Comment: I agree, a weakness of this solution is the algebra required to solve this system would be tedious.

Comment: But when you have three spheres and all of them intersect and have a given r then there are always two points where D possibly can be. Or am i wrong?

Comment: @critiqalfish There will probably be two possible solutions for D. However, it's possible to have only one or none at all.

Comment: Alright thank you. In the case i use this the three spheres always intersect so i always have two possible solutions. But i am very grateful for your answer and i already tried applying it and it serms to work fine. I suppose i can expand this easily to a system of four equations so i am only left with one value. Thank you